# Multiple form not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a `multiWindowsForm`.

Just to try how it is working I started with a a simple form that I added a button to.  When clicking on it, another window should pop up. But I can't get it to work. It crashes with error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object!
```

I used <kbd>Project</kbd> → <kbd>Add</kbd> → <kbd>Windows form</kbd> and named it `Mupp.cs`

Here's my code for `Form1.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultiForm
{
    public partial class tryout : Form
    {
        public tryout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Mupp theMupp;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            theMupp = new Mupp();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            theMupp.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

What can I have missed out on?

Comment: post the code for your Mupp class. also, does it crash on `theMupp.Show()` or somewhere in the Mupp class itself?

Comment: You are probably having an issue when you New up your Mupp Class. We need to see the code.

Comment: I did edit the post with the Mupp.cs  code.  thank you !~

Comment: It looks like Killercam has the right idea, make sure the Form_load EventHandler is attached to the Event. Go to the Property page of your Form click on the lightning bolt and verify that Form_Load is assigned to the Load Event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the load event is not firing and thus not initilising your object. Make sure that the load event is hooked up.

Alternatively, initialise in the click event.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     using (Mupp theMupp = new Mupp())
     {
         theMupp.ShowDialog();
     }
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
public tryout()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
}
```